# How to initialize Python dataclass 2D list?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

Is is possible to create a default initializer to python dataclasses initializing a 2D array, i.e. resulting in the same as

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List
MAX = 5
@dataclass
class AlgoData:
    list2D: List[List[int]]  # = ???
    list1D: List[int] = field(default_factory=list)

b = [[] for m in range(MAX)]
a = AlgoData(b)
```

but without the `b` argument. Result:

```
AlgoData(list2D=[[], [], [], [], []], list1D=[])
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a `lambda` function instead as a `default_factory` for `field`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List
MAX = 5
@dataclass
class AlgoData:
    list2D: List[List[int]] = field(default_factory=lambda: [[] for m in range(MAX)])
    list1D: List[int] = field(default_factory=list)

a = AlgoData()
```

`a` becomes:

```
AlgoData(list2D=[[], [], [], [], []], list1D=[])
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative may be to assign the attributes *after* initialization (via [`__post_init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing)).

**Given**

```
from typing import List

from dataclasses import dataclass, field


MAX = 5
```

**Code**

```
@dataclass
class AlgoData:
    """Algorithm data."""
    list1D: List[int] = None
    list2D: List[List[int]] = field(default_factory=list)

    def __post_init__(self):

        self.list2D = [[] for _ in range(MAX)]
```

**Demo**

```
a = AlgoData()
a
# AlgoData(list2D=[[], [], [], [], []], list1D=[])
```